# T-SQL compare a Number against a padded number substring

Tags: sql, t-sql

The problem is that the COLA has padded 0s

What I am attempting to do is verify COLB, COLC, COLD, COLE, COLF with COLA

Or have I gone about this the wrong way!

How do I get COLB, COLD to compare a Number (int) against a padded number substring ?

---

Example 
that is correct

```
COLB    COLC    COLD    COLE    COLF               COLA

1        DD      5       1       0                     should = 01DD000510
```

not any of these

```
COLB   COLC   COLD  COLE   COLF    COLA

50     AA     230   2       0        0
50     AC     600   3       0
50     AG     740   2       0        50AE074020
50     AS     240   3       0        *0AS024030
```

---

```
 -- select that does not work statement.

 SELECT COLA ,
        COLB ,
        SUBSTRING(COLA, 1, 2) AS 'BLC_COLB' ,
        COLC ,
        SUBSTRING(COLA, 3, 2) AS 'BLC_COLC' ,
        COLD ,
        SUBSTRING(COLA, 5, 4) AS 'BLC_COLD' ,
        COLE ,
        SUBSTRING(COLA, 9, 1) AS 'BLC_COLE' ,
        COLF ,
        SUBSTRING(COLA, 10, 1) AS 'BLC_COLF'
 FROM   ATABLE
 WHERE  SUBSTRING(COLA, 1, 2) NOT LIKE COLB
        OR SUBSTRING(COLA, 3, 2) NOT LIKE COLC
        OR SUBSTRING(COLA, 5, 4) NOT LIKE COLD
        OR SUBSTRING(COLA, 9, 1) NOT LIKE COLE
        OR SUBSTRING(COLA, 10, 1) NOT LIKE COLF

--create table and data script

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATABLE]
    (
      [ROWVERSION] [bigint] NULL ,
      [ROWDATE] [datetime] NULL ,
      [COLB] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [COLC] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL ,
      [COLD] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [COLE] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL ,
      [COLF] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [COLA] [nvarchar](14) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [CON1_0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ( [COLB] ASC, [COLC] ASC, [COLD] ASC, [COLE] ASC, [COLF] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 70 ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
 ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
 SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS, NOCOUNT ON
GO
 SET DATEFORMAT YMD
GO
 SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Add 5 rows to [dbo].[ATABLE] with non-unique comparison key
 SET ROWCOUNT 1
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ATABLE]
        ( [COLB] ,
          [COLC] ,
          [COLD] ,
          [COLE] ,
          [COLF] ,
          [ROWVERSION] ,
          [ROWDATE] ,
          [COLA]
        )
 VALUES ( 1 ,
          N'DD' ,
          5 ,
          N'1' ,
          0 ,
          327520493236000002 ,
          '2011-07-04 10:21:33.227' ,
          N'01DD000510'
        )
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ATABLE]
        ( [COLB] ,
          [COLC] ,
          [COLD] ,
          [COLE] ,
          [COLF] ,
          [ROWVERSION] ,
          [ROWDATE] ,
          [COLA]
        )
 VALUES ( 50 ,
          N'AA' ,
          230 ,
          N'2' ,
          0 ,
          327520514140000004 ,
          '2011-07-28 09:47:41.013' ,
          N'0'
        )
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ATABLE]
        ( [COLB] ,
          [COLC] ,
          [COLD] ,
          [COLE] ,
          [COLF] ,
          [ROWVERSION] ,
          [ROWDATE] ,
          [COLA]
        )
 VALUES ( 50 ,
          N'AC' ,
          600 ,
          N'3' ,
          0 ,
          327520523360000007 ,
          '2011-07-28 09:48:09.577' ,
          N''
        )
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ATABLE]
        ( [COLB] ,
          [COLC] ,
          [COLD] ,
          [COLE] ,
          [COLF] ,
          [ROWVERSION] ,
          [ROWDATE] ,
          [COLA]
        )
 VALUES ( 50 ,
          N'AG' ,
          740 ,
          N'2' ,
          0 ,
          327520543671000002 ,
          '2011-07-28 09:47:03.773' ,
          N'50AE074020'
        )
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ATABLE]
        ( [COLB] ,
          [COLC] ,
          [COLD] ,
          [COLE] ,
          [COLF] ,
          [ROWVERSION] ,
          [ROWDATE] ,
          [COLA]
        )
 VALUES ( 50 ,
          N'AS' ,
          240 ,
          N'3' ,
          0 ,
          327520586618000007 ,
          '2011-07-28 09:48:08.453' ,
          N'*0AS024030'
        )
 SET ROWCOUNT 0
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this to select all rows that are "not verified":

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ATABLE
WHERE   RIGHT('0' + CAST(COLB AS VARCHAR), 2) +
        COLC +
        RIGHT('000' + CAST(COLD AS VARCHAR), 4) +
        COLE +
        CAST(COLF AS VARCHAR) <> COLA
```

Comment: Dillen, RIGHT('000' + CAST(COLD AS VARCHAR), 4) it may not be always three 000 it could be 1, 2 or 3 - 0s, sorry data misleading

Comment: It currently prints all of the rows that have padded 0s in Col A and D as they do not match.

Comment: The query (the second one) returns one row, the row you said was "correct" in your question. The other four are not included. so I'm not sure I understand... Perhaps you could update your question with another `INSERT` into `ATABLE` where this query won't work?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I changed my answer a little bit. If you run that query against your data, does it return any rows that are considered verified?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8922/discussion-between-dillenmeister-and-icecurtain)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the zero-padded number to a integer before doing the comparison.

```
CASE
   WHEN ZeroPadded NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
   THEN CAST(ZeroPadded AS int)
END
```